# VBA - "Compile Error: Method or data member not found"

Tags: ms-access, compiler-errors, vba

I have been developing an Access form to operate as a frontend for a SQL database.  I have been working with a developer, and they added the following VBA code to our main form:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Me.NewRecord = True Then
        Me.Client_Name.Enabled = True
        Me.SSN.Enabled = True
        Me.DOB.Enabled = True
        Me.Prob_Fee.Enabled = True
        Me.Settle_Atty_Amt.Enabled = True
        Me.Settle_Date.Enabled = True
        Me.Final_Date.Enabled = True
    Else
        Me.Client_Name.Locked = True
        Me.SSN.Locked = True
        Me.DOB.Locked = True
        Me.Prob_Fee.Locked = True
        Me.Settle_Atty_Amt.Locked = True
        Me.Settle_Date.Locked = True
        Me.Final_Date.Locked = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When I try to add a new variable to this statement `Me.Case_ID.Locked = True`, the following error is returned:

> Compile Error: Method or data member not found

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Make sure that you are referring to the name of the control that you just added. It may not be the same as the field / column contained. You can use intellisense. When you type `Me.` you will find controls listed amongst the other properties and methods. If Case_ID is not there, that is not the name of the control.

Comment: What I found weird is that when I type Me. it gives me a list of appropriate values and the Case_ID field is one

Comment: Ah, yes, it will also be included as a field, silly me. Just check the form and see what is the name of the control.

Comment: Weird. In my form the name of the control source is listed as Case_ID, so I am not sure what the issue is - I must be missing something

Comment: Not the control source that is the field, the name of the control, on the Other tab of the property sheet, under name.

Comment: Oh! The name did not match and when I changed it the code ran! Thanks for the help - I had a feeling it would be a facepalm kind of problem haha

Comment: Yep :) I generally like to rename controls so I don't run into mix-ups: ID, txtID and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you are referring to the name of the control that you just added. It may not be the same as the field / column contained. On the 'Other' tab of the property sheet, you will find Name, that is the property you need. It is often different from the name of the control contained.

[image: control name]

Comment: Why do I have to relearn this every time I open a VB6 project :)